# Отправка uid пользователя в папку в firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase

У меня есть метод авторизации пользователя через Гугл и надо чтобы после авторизации его uid сразу попадала в папку users в database.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestTemplate можно использовать, например как в keycloak